# Thunderbird - css - primary/("browser"?) page styling - bg img setting

Tags: css, css-selectors, thunderbird

I created a userChrome.css file and am trying to change a few things about my Thunderbird mail client's interface, but i can't figure out what the tag is for the main browser features, such as the background of the non-mail-pages and below the mail list on the mail page.

halp much appreciated <3

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with Thunderbird's UI as compared to Firefox's but see if [this extension](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/dom-inspector-dm) helps you locate those components. Unfortunately I can't help much more than that, though.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I can't get that plugin, due to using a windows computer. seems like most plugins aren't compatible for some reason? I also don't understand why there isn't a 64bit version of thunderbird for windows. As a second question, do you know if the 64bit thunderbird for windows is somehow executable?

Comment: I found the 64 bit download, but yeah, for some reason almost all add-ons aren't available. I'm using v68.9. anyway thanks again